# Integrate angular 8 to grails

Tags: grails

I'm usinga Grails 2.5 with angularjs and works.

Now, I need to use Angular (2 or +). Also I need all the resources to be in the same project, not in two separated projects running independently.

I just he saw examples with grails 3.x but I can't upgrade grails version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I need all the resources to be in the same project, not in two separated projects running independently." - In short you want to do the same thing with Grails 2 that you would with Grails 3+ and that is bundle the SPA inside the jar and serve it up as static resources.  You will need to use some build tool to build your angular 8 app (Grails 2 won't be involved in that) and then include the results of that build in your Grails app .jar.  Are there specific aspects of that that you can ask about?

Comment: Do you mean that can I usea a compiler for angular and it will generate jars?

Comment: "Do you mean that can I usea a compiler for angular and it will generate jars?" - No.  As far as I know there are no compilers for angular that will generate a jar.  The angular build tool is going to generate assets that the Grails build tool should include in the jar.

Comment: I thing that it will be js files

Comment: "I thing that it will be js files" - Agreed.  Since you want all of this served by the same process, you will want all of the SPA assets (including js files but also any CSS, images, and other assets that the front end needs) that come out of the Angular build to be included in the Grails build that is creating the `.jar` file.